# Posting data between Asp.Net Web Pages

Tags: asp.net, forms, post

I have a list of strings, which are generated on a imagebutton_click method. I want to be able to use this list in another webpage.

How ever im not quite sure how to go about posting it between the two pages.

I have the following code below:

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            RadGrid rg = RadGrid1;
            //Get selected rows
            GridItemCollection gdc = (GridItemCollection)rg.SelectedItems;
            foreach (GridItem gi in gdc)
            {
                if (gi is GridDataItem)
                {

                    GridDataItem gdi = (GridDataItem)gi;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gdi["Email"].Text))
                    {

                        string client = gdi["Email"].Text;
                        //Creating a List of Clients to be Emailed
                        emailList.Add(email);

                    }
                }
                        //Enable the Prepare Email Page
                       PageView2.Selected = true;
            }


 protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            if (emailList.Count != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < emailList.Count; i++)
                {
                    _to = emailList[i].ToString() + ";";

                }

            }
            else
            {
                _to = emailList[1].ToString();

            }


            //Processing Client Email
            string _from = sec.GetCurrentUserEmail("test");
            string _cc = "";
            string _subject = SubjectTB.Text;
            string _body = EmailEditor.Content;
            string _tempTo = sec.GetCurrentUserEmail("temp");
            string _msg = sec.SendMail(_tempTo, _cc, _from, _subject, _body, "");

            if (_msg == "success")
            {
                //Thank the user and record mail was delivered sucessfully 
                TestPanel.Visible = true;

            }

        }
```

How do I get the values of emailList to be passed through to ImageButton2_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e). Currently it just passes through a null value. I gather I need to use HTML forms to do the request. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a good idea about state management in ASP.Net [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/z1hkazw7.aspx). For your case if button1 and button2 are in the same aspx page, Viewstate would be a good idea. If they are in diferent pages then use Session state management.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that emailList is a private variable?  Wouldn't you be able to add that to the LoadControlState and SaveControlState so that it'll be available for ImageButton2_Click later?

Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.loadcontrolstate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Another possibility is hidden field, that might be the simplist way, but not as secure.

Comment: Yes it is a private global variable. How would I go about save and loading the control state. Thanks.